# Nginx serves downloadable files

Tags: nginx, django-rest-framework, header, docker-compose

nginx serves downloadable files. I am using django-rest with docker compose. On my PC no code errors are encountered. My nginx config file is as follows:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name  1xxx;   # substitute by your FQDN and machine's IP address
    charset     utf-8;
    add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="file"';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Content-Disposition';
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what the problem you are experiencing is?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the `add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="file"';` header.
If you remove that line it should work just fine.
With [Content-Disposition Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) you notify the browser to download the file instead of rendering it.

> The first parameter in the HTTP context is either inline (default value, indicating it can be displayed inside the Web page, or as the Web page) or attachment (indicating it should be downloaded; most browsers presenting a 'Save as' dialog, prefilled with the value of the filename parameters if present).